# Good readable testnames in c#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, f#, naming

I read in [FsUnit](http://fsunit.codeplex.com/) that the following are valid method/classnames in F#:

```
[<TestFixture>] 
type ``Given a LightBulb that has had its state set to true`` ()=
   let lightBulb = new LightBulb(true)

   [<Test>] member test.
    ``when I ask whether it is On it answers true.`` ()=
       lightBulb.On |> should be True
```

Is there a way to have method or classnames like this in c#?

Comment: Makes you think whether one should formulate tests in F#

Comment: @Frank: really?  Somehow I don't think "the ability to stick a whitespace character in an identifier" ought to be a key feature in determining a choice of programming language.

Comment: @Brian: Having the ability to write tests that are truly human readable (especially by the customer) can have great impacts on my choice of language - At least for definig the tests (which is what Frank was referring to). And by being able to mix all clr languages this does not impact on the choice of language to implement the project with.

Comment: Perhaps I am just old or ignorant, but I think all you "human-readable" agile tester people are just nutso.  :)

Comment: @Brian, it's not just the whitespace, those tests roll off quite nicely...in VS2010 an F# project is just a click away and I usually have my tests in a separate assembly.
@Nils, do you know if resharper supports FsUnit?

Comment: @Frank: It feels like Resharper does currently not supprt f# - does that answer the question ;)

Comment: @Brain, you got a nice laugh out of me there!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you cannot have spaces or punctuation in a C# method name. You can do:

```
[TestMethod]
public void When_Asked_Whether_It_Is_On_It_Answers_True() {}
```

Comment: This is what I expected. I had to ask anyhow...   
Having to write all those underscores does not come naturally to me... And having testnames without underscores would improve readability on test-reports.

Comment: Interestingly you can add escape characters to C# identifier names, so cl\u0061ss is a valid name. However, the escape sequence for space is not valid, so "When\u0021Asked" is not a valid identifier, which rather seems to defeat the point of allowing escape sequences in identifiers. (Admittedly this still looks ugly in source but at least would look nice in a test runner app).

Comment: @Robert - Assuming C# is like Java in this regard, the compiler converts the escape characters to the none-escaped form. It is basically to allow an ASCII files to handle none-ASCII identifiers.

Comment: Why not have a test report tool show test names by replacing underscores with spaces?

Answer (score 1):

do as the book say:

```
public void MethodNameUnderTest_CaseExplained_ExpectedResult()
```

very readable

Comment: Which book are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

My preferred method of naming tests does not include underscores at all.

For example,

```
[Test]
public void SomeMethodShouldCallServiceManagerWithTheCorrectParameters()
```

With that said, consistency is key. There is no penalty for having a method name as long as you want it. So if you prefer to separate words with underscores, then go for it.

Ian

Comment: Having it that way is a pain to read, IMO. It's def harder than reading it with underscores.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there's a horrendous Unicode hack you can do if you *really* want your tests to have spaces in them.

Jimmy Bogard explains:

http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2009/02/16/spaces-in-identifier-names-in-c.aspx

Basically, use a UTF-16 0x200E character as space, hacking your keyboard with AutoHotkey so that you can easily type that character when you need to.

Now the question is, do you really want to do that?